# filter routes request in onRouteRequest play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to web development. I testing my site performance in [gtmetrix.com](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/sinsing.org/SKlv5Yr7) 
they gave me F because I'm not avoid bad request. these request are for my public assets and I want to avoid them and when someone else want to access these routes show 404 error

One solution I think is to filter routes at function onRouteRequest

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  if (request.path.equals("/assets/images/logo.jpg")) {
    // return 404 respond
  }
  super.onRouteRequest(request)
}
```

is it good or is there any solution?

Comment: Instead of using onRouteRequest use GlobalSettings in playframework and route all your Not Found requests to a default 404 Page. for more Info https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

Comment: when Not Found called? based on document I think this function called when route not found, but I need to filter existing route that routing my public folder for example _https://localhost:9000/assets/images/logo.jpg_